# Conversion of Text layers to vector 'Line' Feature Class

Tags: shapefile, labeling, line, convert, geomedia

Is there a way to convert Text or Labels to Vectors within Geomedia or utilize the Publish to KML and convert using Google Earth?

I do not have Adobe Illustrator installed here to 'Create Outlines', and obviously not MAPublisher to import them to Illustrator.

I need to create a shapefile with text and other features displayed as lines within the same shapefile.

Note: I do not wish to export to .dgn and convert using Microstation